# Sinhala Unicode rendering issue in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, unicode

When I Type Sinhala Unicode word "ප්‍රාදේශීය" in JLabel it renders as "ප්රායදේශීය"
I'm using NetBeans 7 in Windows 8.1 (64 bit).
How Do I rectify the above....

Comment: I can't find any code in your question, so I'm only guessing. Try using unicode literals rather than the actual letters, e.g. `new JLabel("\u0d86\u0dba\u0dd4");` By the way, did you try Googling for ___java sinhala unicode___?

Comment: Also, make sure you're using a Font which supports the expected unicode

Comment: @MadProgrammer if the OP isn't using an appropriate font, then he wouldn't see any Sinhala characters at all, would he? I mean he would probably see unreadable symbols, like little squares, right?

Comment: @Abra I couldn't say - it would depend on the Font - that would be my first place to check.  Different fonts do different things ;)

Comment: `\u0DB4\u0DCA\u200D\u0DBB\u0DCF\u0DAF\u0DDA\u0DC1\u0DD3\u0DBA` and `\u0DB4\u0DCA\u0DBB\u0DCF\u0DBA\u0DAF\u0DDA\u0DC1\u0DD3\u0DBA` are different strings (the former contains a _Zero Width Joiner_ (`\u200D` at index 2) while the latter contains _Sinhala Letter Yayanna_ **ය** (`\u0DBA` at index 4)

Comment: I think the problem is with only two characters in "Sinhala" which use non-zero-joint (NZJ). and NZJ doesn't support by Java.

Comment: @Abra I tried literals also but didn't work out.